Envelope of the set of tangent lines of an immersion
Suppose we have a smooth immersion $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^n$, for $n>d$.
Consider the set of tangent planes of the immersion
$$
\mathcal{P}_f:=\{f(x)+\mathrm{span}(\partial_{x_1}f(x),\ldots,\partial_{x_d}f(x))\subset\mathbb{R}^n\}_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}.
$$

Is the image $f(\mathbb{R}^d)$ uniquely determined by $\mathcal{P}_f$?
If not, is it uniquely determined when $f$ is injective, or perhaps when some condition relating $d$ to $n$ holds?

My suspicion is that this question can be thought of by thinking about the envelope of a family of planes, where the envelope of $\mathcal{P}_f$ is $f(\mathbb{R}^d)$, but I haven't gotten far taking that approach. If we parameterize $\mathcal{P}_f=F^{-1}(0)$ for $F:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ some suitably defined smooth function, the envelope would be the set of all points $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for some $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$, we have
$$
F(y,x)=0, \nabla_x F(y,x)=\mathbf{0}.
$$

No. Consider (a) a "fishhook" and (b) a 'closed fishhook' (each with "open" ends, like an open interval). These are both images of immersions of $\mathbb R$ (or equivalently, the interval $0 < x < 1$) into $\mathbb R^2$, and have the same set of tangent lines, but the images of these immersions -- what you see in the two drawings --- are evidently different.
(Apologies for my crude drawing. PowerPoint is not a great tool. This immersion is clearly $C^1$ but not $C^2$ or higher, but it can be smoothed out to be $C^\infty$ ... just not with powerpoint.)


Indeed, any two maps with constant tangent plane on different sizes of subsets will create the same problem (assuming the rest of the domain gives you the same image of the Gauss map).

D'oh! Of course, thank you. The counterexamples jump out at me bit more in light of this. If I develop a reasonable condition where uniqueness does hold, I will be sure to post a reply here (mods allowing).

Thanks for the amplification, Ted. And mrodden, if you think of something that seems like a feasible additional condition, post it as a new question (possibly with a pointer to this one), rather than altering this one after the fact, making this answer and discussion look weird. :) New questions are always welcome.

Indeed, I realize now that my answer should have been "consider the intervals $-1 < x < 1$ on the $x$-axis, and $-2 < x < 2$ on the $x$-axis."  :)
